# Precheck: What are the drawbacks of Material Design?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to ask this question in a community wiki format, because:

- Material design is a major current UX philosophy/framework.
- It is [not that easy](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=(disadvantages%20OR%20drawbacks%20OR%20cons)%20%22material%20design%22) to find articles/blogs containing the drawbacks.
- There are some specific (objective, not subjective) issues with material design including its inefficient use of space and color, its performance issues with heavy reliance on animations, lack of polyfills, etc.

That said, this is a question that has multi-point answers so I thought I'd check in.

I'm generally a fan of broader questions on StackExchange, so this is one example of a topic that could be very helpful to many UX designers.  Do you guys object?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this type of question is that it's likely--at least at this point in time--going to be purely subjective and opinion based. The drawbacks are likely going to depend heavily on context.

Take iOS8, for example. There were dozens and dozens of articles out there talking about both the benefits and drawbacks of it, but at the end of the day, it was mostly just pure commentary and opinion based.

Comment: Thanks... That is what I kinda figured the response might be. I'll hold off for now then... Although I like your other meta question on link-bait topics so will follow that first

Comment: @tohster I do think it's a great question, btw. Just probably not a great fit for StackExchange.